# Rails custom controller action does not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, updates

I have custom controller action for activating a new customer acount in a webshop. I have a model called `customer.rb`. The model generates a key and sends the customer an activation link. The link is routed to the `customers_controller.rb` and the following action:

```
def activate_customer
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    if @customer.present?
     if @customer.activation_key == params[:activation_key]
       @customer.activated = true
       @customer.save
       redirect_to :cart
     else
       redirect_to :root
     end
    else
     redirect_to :root
    end
end
```

I first tried it without `@customer.save` but the record did not update. I have raised before and after `@customer.activated = true` and it all seems fine. The only problem is that the record does does not update. I also checked a possible `attar_accessible` problem, but that's not it (I shut of `attr_accessible` entirely to check). Any ideas? Thanx in advance!

*Edit: checked value of `@customer.save`, returns `false`...

*Edit:

The problem seems to be the password validation on the Customer model. The validations look as follows:

```
# Validations
validates_presence_of :title, :country, :zipcode, :city, :street, :number, :first name, :lastname
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :email => true
validates_confirmation_of :password, :unless => :validate?
validates_presence_of :password
```

Any ideas how to skip validations on this specific controller action? Thanx for thinking with me!

Comment: You first check by puts command that @customer has some value or not.

Comment: A validation may be failing on your customer model. Did you check what `@customer.save` returns? Does it return `false`?

Comment: Okey checked it, it returns false...

Comment: have you checked your @customer.errors ? Perhaps some validations failed.

Comment: Thanx for that pwned! I think the problem has to do with the password field. It validates the presence and confirmation of a password, and I think this prevents the save. Wich brings me to the problem of skipping validations on a single controller action. I've edited the question for this problem;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional validation which is the best practice in this case.

Here is a railscast on that http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

You can then use some code like this:

```
attr_accessor :updating_password

validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => should_validate_password?

def should_validate_password?
  updating_password
end
```

You then need to set updating_password to false if you want to skip validation.

```
@customer.updating_password = false
@customer.save
```

Comment: Thanx for this. Nice simple solution!

Comment: Shouldn't it be ":if => :should_validate_password?" ?

Comment: No because we're calling a method